# Cannot create actionbar menu item using actionbarsherlock

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock, android-viewpager

I'm having trouble with using menu item on action bar using `slidingmenu library` with `actionbarsherlock`.

Anyone can help?

Here is the code

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {   
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        toggle();
        return true;        
    }
    return onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);        
    return true;
}
```

this is the menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item 
    android:id="@+id/print"
    android:title="@string/printItem"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_print"
    android:showAsAction="always" />
<item 
    android:id="@+id/share"
    android:title="@string/shareItem"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_share"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider" />
```

My logcat says that I encountered runtime error at

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);        
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Your logcat says you have a `NullPointerException` in `android.week08.fragments.MAPFragment.onStart` - how is that related to the code you've posted?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I use map fragment to show map view in viewpager. That's working fine on my real device, those logs is pasted from my emulator that doesn't have google play service. The problem is if I don't use `getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);` and add menu item programmatically, it worked. I don't understand the underlying cause :(

Comment: So what's the problem with your menu? Post your logcat of what errors you have received that relate to your menu.

Comment: If you are creating menu in fragment, make sure that you call `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` for example in `onCreate()`.

Comment: @MichałZ. I created menu in `BaseActivity` extends from `SlidingFragmentActivity`.

Comment: @ianhanniballake The problem is if I remove getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu); and add menu item programmatically, it worked. I don't understand the underlying cause :(

Comment: I just updated my logcat on post, pls have a look

Comment: Maybe you should use other library. I recommend official Google's Navigation Drawer: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't really understand your question.
This code works in my app.

in MainActivity

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {   
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        toggle();
        break;
    case R.id.print:
        //your code
        break;
    case R.id.share:
        //your code
        break;
    default: 
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

in Fragment

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_fragment,menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Comment: I think problem is I use viewpager with 2 fragments. If I remove `getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);` and add menu item programmatically, it worked. I don't understand the underlying cause :(

Comment: in my MainActivity is extends _FragmentActivity_ ; and it works fine with `getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);`